# Проверка активностей в приложении

Tags: java, android, kotlin, activity-life-cycle

Как при запуске приложения можно просмотреть какие активити были запущены?

Comment: Все-таки Java или Kotlin?

Comment: @post_zeew лучше бы котлин конечно, но думаю и решение на Java я смогу понять.

Comment: Не понятно зачем вам это вообще надо?

Answer (score 1):

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  m.getRunningTasks(10);
Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> iterator = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)iterator.next();
    int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
    CharSequence desc = runningTaskInfo.description;
    String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
    int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
}
```

Также в данном случае необходимо в андроид-манифесте прописать следующее разрешение:
android.permission.GET_TASKS

Однако начиная с версии 5.0 Lollipop так делать не рекомендуется в связи с соображениями безопасности. Активити-менеджер может получать только активити запущенного приложения. Ниже также пример того, как делать лучше :)

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> appTasks = manager.getAppTasks();
```